# How to center text

Tags: java, android

So I am writing a program which includes a main menu, and for the main menu I use the following code snip, My question is how can I get the items that it makes appear to be centered rather than left align.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Actions));
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Is the main menu a JPanel? by centered, do you mean Horizontally or Vertically? Have you looked at layout managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom TextView and use that instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item`.

For example, create a layout called "textview.xml" and use something like this:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/arrayTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Then just use `R.layout.textview` to reference it in your `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: I have done this but I just keep getting the message when I run it, saying unfortunately this app has stopped

Comment: Interesting. Please append the LogCat to your original question so that I can help you narrow it down.  Make sure you are referencing the FILE, not the actually `TextView` ID.

Comment: Nevermind, I had the xmlns line 2 times by accident sorry, However this code didn't center my text.

Comment: `android:gravity='center'` should have worked. Try `android:layout_gravity="center"` also. Or just do a search. If you are loading the `TextView` as an item, it just comes down to tweaking the `TextView` properly

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed Wrap content to Fill parent and now it seems to work.

Comment: Ah, I forgot I used `wrap_content` in my answer.  `match_parent` is actually the replacement for `fill_parent` in API 8+.  You should actually use that.  `android:gravity` only works for the width of the view, that is why it was not working before.